Default coordinate for OSM XYZ tiles Open Street Map
What is the syntax for the XYZ tiles url?
I want to configure OSM tiles to always open at the same location and zoom. My attempt to edit the url is apparently not correct.

See for example https://docs.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/.

See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

I assume you are talking about the OpenStreetMap.org website? For example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/59.43477/24.73956?
If so, then the format of the three numerical components is zoom/lat/lng, where zoom is an integer zoom level, and lat and lng are the center coordinates. These are not standard "XYZ" format.
If you are trying to get a specific map that happens to use OSM tiles to use a specific viewport, then can you clarify? I see you tagged QGIS so maybe this is a QGIS question unrelated to OSM?
